# How to overplot Graphics on GeoGraphics?

Tags: graphics, geography

I have a parametric plot and a GeoGraphic of the same size and I want to overplot them.  Show doesn't seem to like to use both at the same time though it will display either.  How can I put regular Graphics on top of GeoGraphics?

[image: flightplan]
[image: oceanmap]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You probably don't even want to put a `Graphics` on a `GeoGraphics`, what does the parametric plot represents?

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them unreadable. Please post your actual _Mathematica_ code as text that can be copied and pasted in a _Mathematica_ notebook. Without such, no one will be able to reproduce your problem, nor will they be able to experiment with possible repairs.

Comment: We will also need the definitions of functions you used to make your `ParametricPlot`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to "convert" your `GeoGraphics` object to a `Graphics` object for `Show` to deal with it. You can do so by `Apply`ing (`@@`) the `Graphics` head to the `GeoGraphics` object.

I can't use your parametric plot because it is missing definitions, so the following will serve as an example of combining objects of various provenance:

```
c = Graphics @@ GeoGraphics[Polygon@Entity["Country", "Italy"], GeoBackground -> None];

d = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], FaceForm[Blue], Opacity[0.5], Disk[{12.5, 46}, 1]}];

p = ParametricPlot[{Sin[0.5 t] + 16, Cos[0.6 t] + 50}, {t, 0, 15 Pi}];

Show[c, d, p, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]